# Scala - Encoder missing for type stored in dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, encoder

I am trying to run the following command in Scala 2.2

```
   val x_test0 = cn_train.map( { case row => row.toSeq.toArray } )
```

And I keep getting the following mistake

```
 error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I have already imported implicits._ through the following commands:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Comment: which line is it exactly? this error is shown when you try to create dataset without encoders defined.

Comment: Scala 2.2 is a bit old. You probably meant Spark 2.2.x?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my mistake. It is Spark 2.2.x.

Comment: The error shows like this:                                                                error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       val x_test0 = cn_train.map( { case row => row.toSeq.toArray } )

Comment: The error message tells you that you can't force an array into a dataframe. Try `cn_train.rdd.map{ row => row.toSeq.toArray }`, this would at least give you an RDD of arrays. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: That worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that it cannot find an `Encoder` for a heterogeneous `Array` to save it in a `Dataset`. But you can get an `RDD` of `Array`s like this:

```
cn_train.rdd.map{ row => row.toSeq.toArray }
```